# Круг со скруглёнными краями в libgdx

Tags: java, android, ios, разработка-игр, libgdx

Нарисовать круг в libgdx достаточно просто (`shapeRenderer.circle()`). Но края у него получаются очень рваные. Как нарисовать круг с нормальными (сглаженными) краями? Нужно чтобы работало на android и ios

p.s. они говорят что ShapeRenderer сделан для дебага и не рекомендуется для использования. Но у меня вся игра состоит из кругов. Как мне быть?

Comment: Нарисовать квадрат из двху полигонов и наложить на него текстуру с альфа-каналом в форме круга. Костыль конечно но это дешевле чем круг из 360+ полигонов.

Comment: @igumnov текстура? а если масштабировать? А цвет как менять? Я в этом совсем начинающий, плохо понимаю, как это всё делается, поэтому вообще по хорошему хотелось бы готового метода circle(). Ну а для чего ещё нужны движки тогда?

Comment: Цвет в шейдере легко поменять, если масштабировать то просто увеличьте её разрешение. В конце концов его можно и в 3D редакторе нарисовать и потом выгрузить меш.

Answer (score 1):

Как костыль, в конфиге меняется numSamples. Круг получается не очень круглым, но хотя бы края не рваные. Как он работает - не понимаю. Выглядит нормально при значении ~3

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать класс [`Pixmap`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html)

```
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, Format.RGBA8888);
pixmap.setColor(Color.RED);
pixmap.fillCircle(x, y, radius);
```

Comment: пробовал, тоже самое

Comment: @danpetruk, тогда только шейдеры свои добавлять